# oauth2 in python

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm looking to write a script that tweets from python (such as [here](http://abhi74k.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/tweeting-from-python/)), however when I try and call

```
import oauth2 as oauth
```

I just get this error:

> ImportError: No module named oauth2

Where can I get this module from? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

Comment: Just come across this. How do you install it? When I try and run setup.py Python is failing saying that 'setuptools' is missing. Is this another 3rd party module?

Comment: as far as i can tell, despite the name, simplegeo's python-oauth2 does not do oauth2, just oauth 1a.

Comment: Jamie is correct - see the README.markdown for the project above. The module specified using request signing, which oauth2 no longer requires. This answer clearly isn't correct.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have pip installed. Then in your terminal enter the following command:

```
$ pip install oauth2
```